# XMLHttpRequest error SCRIPT10

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

Hi all I have to connect to an external server to retrieve data.
They told me to use their script and I have to modify something because it was wrong. Now I ahve a problem when I try to lunch my request.
Return me an error into my internet explorer console

> SCRIPT10: The data required for the completion of this operation are
>   not yet available.

This is my javascript page, the problem I think is because the query doesn't finish in time to print my result. How can I print the result when they are ready and don't return me error?
**I have try to comment all my request and leave only the method "open" but the error return me every time**. Why??

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var req = null ;
function sendRequest(){
    var urlStr="www.test.it";
    var xmlString="";
    xmlString+="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><some xml>";

    createHTTPRequestObject();
    var resp = getResponseText(urlStr+"?"+xmlString,null);

    var xmlDoc;
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    xmlDoc.async = false;

    xmlDoc.loadXML(resp);
    alert(xmlDoc.xml);
}

function createHTTPRequestObject(){
    req=null ;
    var pXmlreq = false ;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        pXmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try{
            pXmlreq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e1) {
            try{
                pXmlreq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e2) {
            }
        }
    }
    req = pXmlreq ;
}

function getResponseText(action,query,method,async,contenttype){
    if(method==null){
        method="POST";
    }
    if(async==null){
        async="true";
    }
    if(contenttype==null){
        contenttype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    req.open(method,action, async);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contenttype);
    if(query){
        req.send(query);
    }else{
        req.send();
    }
    return req.responseText ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="Request" value="Request" onclick="sendRequest();"/>
<div id="content" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you talking about...

Comment: My problem is: I have an error I think this error returns to me because I have to wait the query result ready @Sebas

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest`s also work in non-IE browsers.

Comment: Yes but I have some ActiveXObject @MarcelKorpel

Comment: Your query string (`xmlString` in your case) should be encoded with `encodeURIComponent`. When does it output that error message? Use breakpoints and step over your code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok but I think isn't that the problem.. I have commented all my request and leave only the open method but the error return me every time why?

Comment: Are you trying to load data from a different domain also?

Comment: No I don't think.. because if I copy the link to their page with the request it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read the responseText before it is ready. Looks like you are treating a asynchronous call as synchronous. That would be the issue.

Comment: ok but if i comment over the open method and leave only it return me the error why? I have only leave the method open I don't understand why

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: Your `req.responseText` is still `null` when `getResponseText` finishes.

Comment: I have try to comment the response.. the error return me when I call the open method @MarcelKorpel

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: Then set a breakpoint and check the values you pass to `req.open` (is that `urlStr` variable the correct one?).

Comment: yes is correct because if i copyied it into their demo test page it works fine

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri: And the values you pass to `req.open`? Do you have a demo page where we can test this?

Comment: No because is a demo on their server blocked by IP, I think I have solved the problem, I have add the event onreadystatechange and I have change some settings into the browser for the security